# How to configure wagtail to log admin actions

Tags: django, logging, wagtail

Our team at 18F is working on requirements to obtain an Authority to Operate (ATO).  We use Wagtail for our CMS and we currently have the need to log Admin actions.  Django should provide this functionality (and should write logs to the table `django_admin_log`).  However it seems that Wagtail is not logging any Admin actions to that table.  We really need this capability, is there a configuration we are missing to make this happen, or is a code change/modification needed.  Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, Wagtail do not record user's activity in the admin UI, but there is [a feature request](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/496) for this.

You can submit a pull request to add this functionality, if you wish.